# still have issues with Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have been working on this for two days, read everything and I could not get my answer. Thanks in advance for looking at this!!!

I have a query from joining a few tables, it outputs what I am looking for
Here is my select

```
mysql_select_db($database_dbConnect, $dbConnect);
$query_rsMale = "SELECT  r.points, r.license, l.acaNo, l.firstName, l.lastName,   
l.cxage, l.cxcat,l.cxteam, l.city, l.state, l.gender     FROM rankingsM r INNER  
JOIN field f ON  r.license=f.USAC_No INNER JOIN racers l ON  l.usacNo=f.USAC_No
ORDER BY points";
$rsMale = mysql_query($query_rsMale, $dbConnect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsMale = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMale);
$totalRows_rsMale = mysql_num_rows($rsMale);

echo "<br> This is num " . $totalRows_rsMale . "<br>";
```

I have downloaded this to a csv file on other pages and it works fine.
Then I take that array and put it into another array with implode.

```
$newData = implode(",",$row_rsMale );
$newData = mysql_real_escape_string($newData);

echo "<br> This is newdata <br>". $newData;
```

This is where I get the Column not matching error.
I have checked the column they match, I have checked the data types, they match.

```
 $insertSQL ="INSERT INTO ranking (points, usacNo, acaNo, firstName, lastName,
 cxage, cxcat, cxteam, city, state, gender)
 SELECT ( '$newData' )";

 $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $dbConnect) or die(mysql_error());

 echo "<br>Insert complete!<br>";
```

Next I did a display of the columns

```
 $rankingSQL ="Select * from ranking";

 $result = mysql_query($rankingSQL, $dbConnect) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
$field_info = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
echo "<th>{$field_info->name},</th>";
}
```

This is what is displaying on my page on my website
This is before insert
This is num 22

This is newdata 
185.34,362355,4174,Shawn,Lortie,47,2,Rally Sport Cycling Team,BOULDER,CO,M
points, usacNo, acaNo, firstName, lastName, cxage, cxcat, cxteam, city, state, gender,
(I added the commas on the columns for easy reading.) 
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I ended up going back to ` 
    while ($l = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                    {

```
{
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO ranking (points, usacNo, acaNo, firstName,   
lastName, cxage, cxcat, cxteam, city, `state`, gender) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['points'], "double"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['license'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['acaNo'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['firstName'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['lastName'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['cxage'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['cxcat'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['cxteam'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['city'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['state'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($l ['gender'], "text"));

  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $dbConnect) or die("<br>Error is " . mysql_error());
}`
```

Comment: Are there any commas in the actual data values? And you really should be using built-in functions like fputcsv() and fgetcsv() to write and read your CSV file

Comment: I did on the other pages, this page is not to write to csv files, it is to insert into another table. I was stating the the complex join was getting me the data I wanted.

Comment: There are no commas in actual data values.

Comment: I did not add the commas into the newdata displayed. Do you think it is the issue?

Comment: I thought after the impolde I needed to use the mysql_real_escape_string to remove them?

Comment: I went back in and took out the commas I did for visual reading No this is newdata 
134.20,363631,4089,Steven,Stefko,37,1,Fort Collins Cycling Team,FORT COLLINS,CO,Mpoints  usacNo  acaNo  firstName  lastName  cxage  cxcat  cxteam  city  state  gender  Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the following statement:

```
$insertSQL ="INSERT INTO ranking (points, usacNo, acaNo, firstName, lastName,
                                  cxage, cxcat, cxteam, city, state, gender)
             SELECT ( '$newData' )";
```

Once php expands this with your data, you will have the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO ranking (points, usacNo, acaNo, firstName, lastName,
                     cxage, cxcat, cxteam, city, state, gender)
SELECT ( '185.34,362355,4174,Shawn,Lortie,47,2,Rally Sport Cycling Team,BOULDER,CO,M' )
```

The SELECT is returning one field.  So you are feeding one field to an insert statement with 11 fields and this generates the error.

You need to form the insert correctly, perhaps something like:

```
$newData = implode("','",$row_rsMale );
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO ranking (...) VALUES ('$newData')";
```

This should result in the following:

```
INSERT INTO ranking (...) VALUES ('185.34','362355','4174','Shawn','Lortie','47','2','Rally Sport Cycling Team','BOULDER','CO','M')
```

This isn't optimal as it surrounds numeric arguments with quotes, but perhaps your database will do the conversion.

If you don't have to go through the CSV step, then I would do the insert with a subselect, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO ranking (points, usacNo, acaNo, firstName, lastName,
                     cxage, cxcat, cxteam, city, state, gender) 
(SELECT  r.points, r.license, l.acaNo, l.firstName, l.lastName,
                     l.cxage, l.cxcat,l.cxteam, l.city, l.state, l.gender
FROM rankingsM r 
INNER JOIN field f ON r.license=f.USAC_No 
INNER JOIN racers l ON l.usacNo=f.USAC_No
ORDER BY points)
```

One operation does the whole thing and returns the number of rows inserted.  No type wrangling, and very efficient from a database/app perspective as you are not pulling all of the data back into PHP just to feed it back in again.

Comment: It didn't like that. If I take this select query and either sql the database directly within phpAdmin or use it to create a csv file it works. When I put it here copy and pasted from other working files a second time to make sure no typos It tells me I have an error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM rankingsM r INNER JOIN field f ON r.license=f.USAC_No INNER JOIN racers l ' at line 3

Comment: Sounds like you tried the insert/select?  Could you show the updated code?

Comment: I wanted to do the insert/select I updated it on the top I think. Not used to this.